# Forward function parameter arg in lua

Tags: function, parameters, lua, arguments

I would like to override a function to inspect its parameter values but the call it and pass the original parameters as normal. Is this possible? I am using Corona SDK by www.coronalabs.com

My code at present, which does not work, is:

```
-- getting a refrence to the original function so i can replace it with my overriding function
local newcircle = display.newCircle

-- my override
display.newCircle = function(...)
-- attempt to pass the parameters to this function on to the real function
local t = {...}
newcircle(unpack(t))
end

-- calling the overridden function as if it were normal
display.newCircle( display.newGroup(), "image.png" )
```

Comment: If `newCircle` takes two arguments, why complicate matters with `...`.?

Comment: You should leave the original (problematic) code in the question.  If you replace it with the corrected version, it is difficult for others to see the original meaning of the question.

Answer (score 1):

In your new `display.newCircle` implementation, you are using the undefined `t` table, and the deprecated `arg` automatic table.

Try this :

```
-- my override
display.newCircle = function(...)
    local t = {...} -- you need to collect arguments to a table
    -- dumb use of override
    print(t[1])
    -- attempt to pass the parameters to this function on to the real function
    newcircle(unpack(t))
end
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out - you're right, I was being extra dumb. However the error I get is: bad argument #2 to 'newcircle' (number expected, got string)

Comment: I believe the problem occurs because the unpacking of the table returns the index values of the table entries as well as the entries. I just don't see a way round it.

Comment: `unpack` only returns values, not keys. In your code, you have effectively passed a string as the second argument: `"image.png"`

Comment: thank you :) - I was passing incorrect parameters - i should have been using a call to override newImage() !